# Animate component when state changes in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a small animation on HTML element when data values stored in state change. How can achieve that?

How can I add a CSS class to component in `componentWillUpdate` and remove it in `componentDidUpdate`? I don't see any reference to any HTML element there.

Comment: I recommend to read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

Comment: Or you could also simply search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breactjs%5D+animation

Comment: I tried, but I used wrong keywords. I got only a couple of results.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add a class to a component: `React.findDOMNode(this).classList.add("classname");`

To remove:
`React.findDOMNode(this).classList.remove("classname");`

If you're trying to add a class in `componentWillUpdate` and remove it in `componentDidUpdate`, you'd need to use something like a setTimeout to notice a change. For example:

```
componentWillUpdate: function() {
    React.findDOMNode(this).classList.add("class1", "class2");
},
componentDidUpdate: function() {
    var el = React.findDOMNode(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
       el.classList.remove("class1");
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that React.findDOMNode is deprecated.Use ReactDOM.findDOMNode from require('react-dom') instead.

Comment: You'll probably want to clear that timeout in `componentWillUnmount`.